How to take a portion of the images in the Photos.app out of iCloud sync
Currently I am syncing my complete Photos library via iCloud.
Now I want to take a portion of the images in the Photos.app out of iCloud sync, so that I reduce the amount of space my Photos library takes up in iCloud.
It would be ideal if I could keep the images I take out of iCloud sync still in the Photos.app on my Mac (for searching, etc).
If this is not possible, can I move the images I take out of iCloud sync, into another Photos library which as a whole is not synced with iCloud?
Many thanks for any help in advance.

You can use 3rd Party software like the proprietary PowerPhotos app to move photos from your main iCloud-synced library into a new Photo library.
Then you can switch between these libraries as in @LincDavis' answer described.

A+ suggestion for power photos. It’s incredible for managing multiple libraries and also cleaning up when things go wrong.


You can create additional photo libraries to organize your photos, albums, and projects, and then switch between the libraries.
Important: If you use iCloud Photos, remember that only the photos and video in your System Photo Library are uploaded to iCloud. Be sure to back up all of your photo libraries.

https://support.apple.com/guide/photos/create-additional-libraries-pht6d60b524/mac

That's a good idea. Thanks.

@linc-d That article doesn't seem to detail how you tell which of several libraries is the "system" library.  If you use Photos.app, is there a way to tell?  I don't.

The easiest way to tell is that the “system“ library is the one that syncs with other devices. It’s also the one that was created automatically when Photos was first launched, inside the Pictures folder.

@LincD. So there's no indication in the app?
